# Why does this cause an overflow?

Tags: c, overflow, stdint

It's my understanding that uint64_t defined by C99 (stdint.h) is defined to be 8 bytes (= 64 bits) of length, thus allowing for a maximum value of 2^64 - 1. However, when I try the following code snippet, the uint64_t overflows, even though it's nowhere near 2^64 - 1:

```
uint64_t Power10(int exponent)
{
    int i = 1;
    uint64_t ret = 10;
    while(i < exponent)
    {
        ret *= 10;
        ++i;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you determining that "ret" is overflowing?

Comment: At what iteration or value of `i` does it overflow?

Comment: at what value of `exponent` does `ret` overflow?

Comment: which value of exponent are you passing to your function?

Comment: It would be more correct to have `i` start at `0` and `ret` start at `1`.  You are probably trying to pass in `64` and getting a off-by-one error.

Comment: I've determined that ret's overflowing by printing its value; it should go something like 10, 100, ..., 10000000000, but it becomes something like: 1410065408, which seems like an overflow to me. And I've tried the off-by-one approach, and it doesn't quite seem to work. Incidentally, i is (at most) 11, and it works fine with i = 9.

Comment: Exactly how are you printing the value?  Why not post a complete example that shows the problem?  That way no one has to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to print with `"%" PRIu64` conversion. Don't forget to add the right include!

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Power10(12) is %" PRIu64 "\n", Power10(12));
    return 0;
}
```